# Multiline copyright message with \IEEEpubid?

Tags: formatting

I am asked to add a long copyright notice at the center of the bottom of the first page. I tried using `\IEEEpubid{copyright notice}` for that.

But the text does not fit to one line and line breaks `\\` are ignored.

Does anybody know how to insert a multiline copyright notice?

Comment: try  `\IEEEpubid{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}zzz\\zzz\\zzz\end{tabular}}`

Comment: Perfect, this works exactly like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tabular in most contexts to get multiple lines into a one-line box.

```
 \IEEEpubid{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}zzz\\zzz\\zzz\end{tabular}}
```